# Simple server for SOAP Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am creating a SOAP service and I do not give with it.

I have these files

```
server.php

<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
function simpleFunction() {
return 'simpleFunction'; 
}

// initialize SOAP Server
$server=new SoapServer("simple.wsdl");

$server->addFunction('simpleFunction');

$server->handle();
```

&

```
simple.wsdl


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Simple"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              targetNamespace="Simple"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:tns="Simple"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:message name="simpleFunctionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in1" type="xsd:string"></wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="in2" type="xsd:string"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="simpleFunctionResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="out1" type="tns:integer"></wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="out2" type="xsd:string"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="Simple">
    <wsdl:operation name="simpleFunction">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:simpleFunctionRequest"/>

        <wsdl:output message="tns:simpleFunctionResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="Simple" type="tns:Simple">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" 
transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="simpleFunction">
        <soap:operation 
soapAction="http://192.168.56.2/ws/verySimple/server.php"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="Simple"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="Simple"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="Simple">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:Simple" name="Simple">
        <soap:address 
location="http://192.168.56.2/ws/verySimple/server.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

to prove it I created this client

```
client.php

<?php
$in1='in1';
$in2='in2';

$client=new SoapClient('simple.wsdl',               
['trace'=>1,'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE]);
$resp  =$client->simpleFunction($in1, $in2);

// dump response
var_dump($resp);
```

I have started a server in XAMP and if I make a call to the client.php it returns this:

```
array (2) {["out1"] => NULL ["out2"] => NULL}
```

I also try the service with SoapUI doing a project with the url

```
http: //localhost/verySimple/simple.wsdl
```

and gives me a Request for SimpleFuntion

```
<soapenv: Envelope xmlns: soapenv = 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns: sim = "Simple">
<soapenv: Header />
<soapenv: Body>
<sim: simpleFunction>
<in1>? </ in1>
<in2>? </ in2>
</ sim: simpleFunction>
</ soapenv: Body>
</ soapenv: Envelope>
```

and response

```
<SOAP-ENV: Envelope xmlns: SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns: ns1 = "Simple">
   <SOAP-ENV: Body>
      <ns1: simpleFunctionResponse />
   </ SOAP-ENV: Body>
</ SOAP-ENV: Envelope>
```

If I copy the same service (changing the url from http: // localhost to http://192.168.56.2/ws/) to another server that I have in a virtual machine

and I call the client.php it does not show me anything

and if I use SoapUi against http://192.168.56.2/ws/verySimple/simple.wsdl

The request returns

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:sim="Simple">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <sim:simpleFunction>
     <in1>?</in1>
     <in2>?</in2>
  </sim:simpleFunction>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but there is no response ...

I guess the problem is configuring the second server, but I do not know what I have to do it respond. Can you help me?

**Bonus Question :-):**

In localhost the the

```
var_dump($resp);
```

is

```
array (2) {["out1"] => NULL ["out2"] => NULL}
```

but I don't know how to fill this array because the function

```
return 'simpleFunction';
```

but I don't know where is this string :-(

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the response from the function as being a type like this:

```
class simpleFunctionResponse {
    public $out1;
    public $out2;
}
```

But the function actually returns a string.

Try something like:

```
// Using the class defined above
function simpleFunction() {
    return new simpleFunctionResponse();
}

// or just with an array
function simpleFunction() {
    return array(
        'out1' => 1,
        'out2' => 'my string',
    );
}
```